# Consulta MySQL counts a 0 con Joins

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo estas cuatro tablas relacionadas entre si (haced caso omiso de las relaciones que van hacia arriba).

[image]

Usaré una consulta para que podáis entender el problema, que es complejo:

```
SELECT u.nombre, COUNT(fr.id_tipologia), t.nombre 
FROM tipologias AS t 
INNER JOIN fr 
  ON t.id = fr.id_tipologia 
INNER JOIN encargos AS e 
  ON fr.id_encargo = e.id 
INNER JOIN usuarios AS u 
  ON e.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario 
GROUP BY u.nombre, fr.id_tipologia
```

La lectura de la consulta sería algo como: Dime cuántas tipologías y con qué nombre tiene asignada cada usuario.

Esto me resulta lo siguiente:

[image]

Por ahora todo correcto, los datos en esencia son los que necesito, el tema es que esos datos son para mostrarlos en un gráfico, por tanto necesito los null de las relaciones por cuestiones de ordenación de datos a la hora de interpretarlos en el gráfico.

Concretamente la "pregunta" que quiero hacer a la base de datos sería:
¿Qué tipologías no están asignadas a cada usuario?
Es decir, la respuesta de esa consulta sería algo así:

```
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
|      nombre      | COUNT(fr.id_tipologia) |      nombre      |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Desarrollo       | 29                     | Plaza de parking |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Desarrollo       | 22                     | Vivienda         |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Desarrollo       | 4                      | Oficina          |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Desarrollo       | 4                      | Local            |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Nombre de Testeo | 0                      | Plaza de parking |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Nombre de Testeo | 1                      | Vivienda         |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Nombre de Testeo | 0                      | Oficina          |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Nombre de Testeo | 0                      | Local            |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

No he conseguido sacarlo con los left y los right join, y el outer joins no se puede usar en MySQL tengo entendido.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, ¡muchas gracias!

Añado también los resultados con LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT u.nombre, COUNT(fr.id_tipologia), t.nombre 
FROM tipologias AS t 
LEFT JOIN fr 
    ON t.id = fr.id_tipologia 
LEFT JOIN encargos AS e 
    ON fr.id_encargo = e.id 
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS u 
    ON e.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario 
GROUP BY u.nombre, fr.id_tipologia
```

[image]

Comment: Hola, deberia funcionarte con left joins, que resultado te da?

Comment: Hola! con left join en todas las relaciones obtengo las tipologías que no están asignadas a ningún usuario, y con todas en right join, obtengo los usuarios que no tienen ninguna tipología asignada.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la consulta que haces con left join?

Comment: @JavierMollá Añadido

Comment: Hay un problema de orden en tus querys. Si la consulta estuviera ordenada te daria el resultado que buscas. Primero, entra por la tabla que quieres agrupar. Despues ve uniendole lo otro que necesitas, de a una. si haces un fiddle en algun lado con datos de ejemplo creo que podria ayudar a resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si dividamos el problema en dos. Ya tienes todos aquellos registros que tienen un contador, solo nos faltan todos aquellos cuyo contador es cero.

Partiendo de una línea de base dónde estén todos los registros con valor 0, que podemos hallar fácilmente con:

```
select u.Nombre usuarioNombre, 0 contador, t.nombre tipologiaNombre
  from usuarios u
       cross join tipologias t
```

Para lograr el resultado final se me ocurre varias maneras de lograr esto, una de ellas podría ser hacer una union de ambas consultas en una tabla derivada, para finalmente hacer un sum().

algo en la línea de:

```
select usuarioNombre, sum(contador) Contador, tipologiaNombre
  from (
        select u.Nombre usuarioNombre, 0 contador, t.nombre tipologiaNombre
          from usuarios u
               cross join tipologias t
        union all
        select u.nombre, COUNT(fr.id_tipologia), t.nombre
          from tipologias AS t
               inner join fr on t.id = fr.id_tipologia
               inner join encargos AS e on fr.id_encargo = e.id
               inner join usuarios AS u   ON e.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
         group by u.nombre, fr.id_tipologia
) q1
group by usuarioNombre, tipologiaNombre
```